# Android Project in eclipse is no where to find

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I already try all the things I searched online such as uninstall the sdk, eclipse and download everything but I still can't find "Android Project" from New > Other. And also from Window>Customize Perspective. But I still can't find it.

I am doing this to learn android programming and I am a beginner with this android programming so I would also appreciate it if you guys would tell me how I can start this and what tutorials you guys recommend.

I have Eclipse IDE for Java Developers(Juno).
ADT version: 21.0

Is it possible that "Android Project" is deleted in new ADT version and replace with Android Application Project?

Comment: No. It is there. Which Android SDK you installed ?

Comment: -This tutorial on how to install Android SDK + ADT http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html - There are large number of video tutorials about Android development in you tube which you can freely download. As a beginner you can learn nuts and bolts of Android from Lynda.com Android development video tutorials. And always you can use Android developers site for examples developer.android.com/index.html - Your this question "Is it possible that "Android Project" is deleted in new ADT version and replace with Android Application Project?" is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

It is now called **Android Application Project**. Try that. You will find it as usual under new - other - android - android application project. And as i understood you, you are right. They renamed it in some earlier adt release.

As a tutorial i would recommend http://www.vogella.com/articles/Android/article.html to you. Quite good explained and easy to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the ADT plugin again.
(Not zip file, use the menu "install new software" on Help menu.

Otherwise, how about installing the another eclipse version instead of the JUNO.